# How can I make dynamic Grid (or Matrix) fields in the control panel?

Tags: matrix, relationships, control-panel, grid, dynamic

I have two Grid fields, the first of which is a Relationship field.
I need the second Grid field's format to change based on the selection made in the first field.

For exmample:

- If Grid Field 1 = A then Grid Field 2 = Text Input
- If Grid Field 1 = B then Grid Field 2 = Time
- If Grid Field 1 = C then Grid Field 2 = Date

...and so on.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not. The simplest solution is to have all four columns and simply instruct the content manager to use the appropriate 2nd, 3rd, or 4th column based on the value of the 1st.